# Include errors in R markdown package vignette

Tags: r, r-package, vignette

I'm developing an R package and have a custom function which contains a `if(condition) stop("Error message")` conditional. I call this function in a package vignette with the intention of generating the error message and including that in the vignette. However, this is causing vignette building to fail.

How can I force vignette building to proceed even when the code generates error messages, and retain those error messages in the vignette document?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [knitr chunk options documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) says:

> `error`: (TRUE; logical) whether to preserve errors (from stop()); by default, the evaluation will not stop even in case of errors!! if we want R to stop on errors, we need to set this option to FALSE

`rmarkdown`'s `render()` function resets this to be `FALSE` by default (unlike `knitr` itself), arguably a better default.  You can override this and set it back to `TRUE` by (I think) either

- setting `error=TRUE` in the options for a particular chunk, or
- using `knitr::opts_chunk$set(error=TRUE)` in an early code chunk to set the option globally.

I would suggest the former (i.e., only allow errors where you are expecting them ...)